# 100% CPU usage with

Tags: central-processing-unit, mod-fcgid, usage

My server is having a problem with high cpu usage and 503 error occured all the time for a certain domain which is being hosted on my server together with other websites. The other websites on the same server are working fine. The problem only happens to this domain with the folllowing error:

```
[Sat Sep 26 12:15:08.831092 2015] [fcgid:warn] [pid 7760:tid 140509674608384] [client 5.157.42.89:44960] mod_fcgid: can't apply process slot for /usr/local/safe-bin/fcgid55.sh /usr/local/directadmin/data/users/aaa/php/aaa.com.ini -d sendmail_from="aaa@aaa.com" -d open_basedir="/home/aaa/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/usr/local/php55/lib/php/" -d mail.log="/home/aaa/.php/php-mail.log", referer: http://aaa.com/
```

And got around 7-10 process pids @ 100% cpu usage with the same commandline:

```
/usr/local/php55/bin/php-cgi55 -d sendmail_from="aaa@aaa.com" -d open_basedir="/home/aaa/:/tmp:/var/tmp:/usr/local/lib/php/:/usr/local/php55/lib/php/" -d mail.log="/home/aaa/.php/php-mail.log"
```

My server is on Centos 6. Directadmin. Nginx with Apache 2.4.16. Php 5.5.

Comment: So you've got seven to ten PHP processes using all available CPU for sending mail? That sounds rather like that you may have an insecure PHP script being abused by spammers.